# registration form window not showing properly

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am new with pyqt5. I made two windows using qt designer and converted them to python code using pyuic. I also connected the register button to show the registration form window when i click it. But now when i run the program and click the register button only the submit button is displayed in the registration from window and the rest of it is totally empty.

[image: this was supposed to be displayed when i click register]

[image: but when i click the register button i get this output]

this is the file with the main window

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from regform import Ui_cnum

class Ui_Form(object):
    def add(self):
        self.window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.ui= Ui_cnum()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(187, 167)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.register_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.register_2.setObjectName("register_2")
        self.register_2.clicked.connect(self.add)
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.register_2)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.update = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.update.setObjectName("update")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.update)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem3)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem4)
        self.remove = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.remove.setObjectName("remove")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.remove)
        spacerItem5 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem5)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        spacerItem6 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem6)
        self.list = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.list.setObjectName("list")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.list)
        spacerItem7 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem7)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        spacerItem8 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem8)
        self.verify = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.verify.setObjectName("verify")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.verify)
        spacerItem9 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem9)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "User Menu"))
        self.register_2.setText(_translate("Form", "Register"))
        self.update.setText(_translate("Form", "Update"))
        self.remove.setText(_translate("Form", "Remove"))
        self.list.setText(_translate("Form", "List"))
        self.verify.setText(_translate("Form", "Verify"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and this is the file with the registration form window

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_cnum(object):
    def setupUi(self, cnum):
        cnum.setObjectName("cnum")
        cnum.resize(400, 300)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(cnum)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(cnum)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.fname = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(cnum)
        self.fname.setObjectName("fname")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.fname)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout)
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(cnum)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.label_2)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.lname = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(cnum)
        self.lname.setObjectName("lname")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.lname)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.horizontalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_3.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_3")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(cnum)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.label_3)
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.cnic = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(cnum)
        self.cnic.setObjectName("cnic")
        self.horizontalLayout_3.addWidget(self.cnic)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_4 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_4.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_4")
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(cnum)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.label_4)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addItem(spacerItem3)
        self.regno = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(cnum)
        self.regno.setObjectName("regno")
        self.horizontalLayout_4.addWidget(self.regno)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_4)
        self.horizontalLayout_5 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_5.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_5")
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(cnum)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.label_5)
        spacerItem4 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addItem(spacerItem4)
        self.eno = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(cnum)
        self.eno.setObjectName("eno")
        self.horizontalLayout_5.addWidget(self.eno)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_5)
        self.horizontalLayout_6 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_6.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_6")
        self.label_6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(cnum)
        self.label_6.setObjectName("label_6")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.label_6)
        spacerItem5 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addItem(spacerItem5)
        self.cno = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(cnum)
        self.cno.setObjectName("cno")
        self.horizontalLayout_6.addWidget(self.cno)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_6)
        self.horizontalLayout_7 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_7.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_7")
        self.label_7 = QtWidgets.QLabel(cnum)
        self.label_7.setObjectName("label_7")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.label_7)
        spacerItem6 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addItem(spacerItem6)
        self.papa = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(cnum)
        self.papa.setObjectName("papa")
        self.horizontalLayout_7.addWidget(self.papa)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_7)
        self.horizontalLayout_8 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_8.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_8")
        spacerItem7 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addItem(spacerItem7)
        self.submit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(cnum)
        self.submit.setObjectName("submit")
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addWidget(self.submit)
        spacerItem8 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(40, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_8.addItem(spacerItem8)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_8)

        self.retranslateUi(cnum)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(cnum)

    def retranslateUi(self, cnum):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        cnum.setWindowTitle(_translate("cnum", "Registration Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("cnum", "First Name"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("cnum", "Last Name"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("cnum", "CNIC"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("cnum", "Registration Number"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("cnum", "Engine Number"))
        self.label_6.setText(_translate("cnum", "Chassis Number"))
        self.label_7.setText(_translate("cnum", "Father\'s Name"))
        self.submit.setText(_translate("cnum", "Submit"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    cnum = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_cnum()
    ui.setupUi(cnum)
    cnum.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `Ui_cnum.setupUi` expects a `QtWidget` as input argument, but you are supplying a `QMainWindow`. You could try using `self.window = QtWidgets.QWidget()` in `Ui_Form.add()`.

Comment: @Heike thanks a lot. That got the job done!